# How to make fast bulk Inserts in VoltDB with Python

Tags: python, database, voltdb

I have a database named "filecards" with six columns:

```
card_id         INT             NOT NULL    UNIQUE,
question        VARCHAR(500),
answer          VARCHAR(500),
creation_time   INT             NOT NULL,
interval_time   INT             NOT NULL,
box_id          SMALLINT        NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(card_id)
```

What is the best way to make fast bulk inserts into that table with the python driver?